# how to start jboss ; how to exclude appxml ; how to make .har file using ant build.xml

Tags: ant, build, jboss, hudson

1. How to start and stop Jboss from Command prompt in windows 7 32bit

when i try to run run.bat file from command prompt i get following error

```
D:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin>run.bat
Calling D:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\run.conf.bat
Could not locate "D:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\bin\bin\run.jar".
Please check that you are in the bin directory when running this script.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

1. How to start and stop jboss from apache ant build.xml file
2. How to make .har file for Hibernate project in java using apache ant build.xml
3. I don't want to include appxml in generated file using ant

   **appxml="..\PartyEJB\ejbModule\META-INF\ejb-jar.xml"**

   ```
   <ear destfile="${EAR}/PartyEAR.ear" appxml="..\PartyEJB\ejbModule\META-INF\ejb-jar.xml">
       <fileset dir="${class}" includes="PartyEJB.jar"/>

       <zipfileset dir="${lib.dir}" prefix="lib">
           <include name="PartyEJBClient.jar"/>
       </zipfileset>

   </ear>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

set JBOSS_HOME environment variable to D:\jboss-6.1.0.Final and then run run.bat

Answer (score 0):

Verify that in your build.xml you are referring to the bin location directly, where as Ant trying to add bin to the path you have mentioned. Please remove /bin in build.xml from where you are invoking.

If it's a Web-Project or Java EE project, Dynamic Web project which doesn't have EJB's wouldn't require appxml.